# How can I make fetch calls to two different APIs and match the username from the first one to the respective username of the 2nd one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

API 'A' will give me the username.
API 'B' will give me the image.
I have to pass the username I get from API 'A' as an argument to API 'B' and API 'B' will then return an image assigned to that username.

I then have to display all the information from API 'A' along with the image from API 'B'.

Here is what I tried:

Parent Component

```
  import DataItem from "./DataItem";
  import React, { Component } from "react";

  export default class DataList extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
     data: [],
     };

     console.log("constructor datalist");
    }

   componentDidMount = async () => {
     var response = await 
     fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
      method: "GET",
      });
     var information = await response.json();
     console.log("did mount datalist", information);
     this.setState({ data: information });
    };


    render() {
      console.log("render datalist");
      return (
       <ul>
           {this.state.data.map((info) => {
             return (
              <li key={info.username}>
                <DataItem allData={info} />
              </li>
             );
            })}
       </ul>
      );
     }

     componentDidCatch(error, info) {
     //console.log("componentDidCatch ", error, info);
      localStorage.lastError = `${error}\n 
      ${JSON.stringify(info)}`;
     }
     }
```

Child

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DataImageItem from "./DataImageItem";

export default class DataItem extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
  allData: { userData: this.props.allData, userImage: [] },
 };
 console.log("constructor dataitem ", this.state.allData);
 }

 componentDidMount = async () => {
  var response = await fetch(
  "https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/
  {{this.state.allData.userData.username}}.
   svg?options[mood][]=happy",
  {
    method: "GET",
  }
 );
var information = await response.json();
console.log("didmount dataitem", information);
this.setState({ ...this.state.allData, userImage: information 
});
 };

  render() {
  console.log("render DataItem");
   return (
  <div className="card card-style">
    <div className=" card-horizontal">
      {this.state.allData.userImage.map((info) => {
        return <DataImageItem cardDataImage={info} />;
      })}
      <div className="card-body card-body-style">
        <h2 className="card-title card-title-style">
          {this.state.allData.userData.name}
        </h2>
        <div className="info">
          <p>
            <strong>Email: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.email}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Phone: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.phone}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Company: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.company.name}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Website: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.website}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Address: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.address.street},{" "}
            {this.state.allData.userData.address.suite},
            {this.state.allData.userData.address.city},{" "}
            {this.state.allData.userData.address.zipcode}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

DataItem's Child

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DataImage from "./DataImage";

 export default class DataImageItem extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    cardDataImage: this.props.cardDataImage,
   };
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="img-square-wrapper p-2">
       {this.state.cardDataImage.map((image) => {
         return <DataImage imageData={image} />;
        })}
     </div>
  );
 }
}
```

DataImageItem's Child

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class DataImage extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

    this.state = {
     imageData: this.props.imageData,
   };
 }
  render() {
   return <img className="profile-img" src= 
    {this.state.imageData} alt="" />;
  }
 }
```

Comment: API A : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

API B: [link] (https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/
  {{username}}.
   svg?options[mood][]=happy)

Answer (score 0):

```
"https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/
  {{this.state.allData.userData.username}}.
   svg?options[mood][]=happy"
```

Should be

```
`https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/
  ${this.state.allData.userData.username}.
   svg?options[mood][]=happy`
```

You are using a react template string in a basic javascript string. So {{this.state.allData.userData.username}} was sent literaly.

Comment: I tried your solution, but my userImage array still has 0 elements.

Answer (score 0):

In the `componentDidMount` of your `DataItem` component, you'd want to inject or dynamically include the value received from the parent component as a `prop`, this could be accomplished using **template literals**, wherein you place your string value within backticks instead of single or double quotes(',""), this would then enable you to inject values using the **${}** syntax. 
Also, you are trying to set an `image` to array and then trying to **map** over it in `DataItem` component. Since you are already mapping in the parent component, the child component and its children component(s) would be rendered for each item, so it is better advised to set the `userImage` property to the image URL directly and send data down to other child components. So you could remove `componentDidMount` in your `DataItem` component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DataImageItem from "./DataImageItem";

export default class DataItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   allData: { userData: this.props.allData, userImage: 
    `https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/
    ${this.state.allData.userData.username}.svg?options[mood][]=happy` },
   };
   console.log("constructor dataitem ", this.state.allData);
  }
  render() {
  console.log("render DataItem");
   return (
  <div className="card card-style">
    <div className=" card-horizontal">
      
      <DataImageItem cardDataImage={this.state.userImage} />; {//Remove mapping}
      
      <div className="card-body card-body-style">
        <h2 className="card-title card-title-style">
          {this.state.allData.userData.name}
        </h2>
        <div className="info">
          <p>
            <strong>Email: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.email}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Phone: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.phone}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Company: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.company.name}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Website: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.website}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Address: </strong>
            {this.state.allData.userData.address.street},{" "}
            {this.state.allData.userData.address.suite},
            {this.state.allData.userData.address.city},{" "}
            {this.state.allData.userData.address.zipcode}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

**DataItemImage**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DataImage from "./DataImage";

 export default class DataImageItem extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    cardDataImage: this.props.cardDataImage, //Contains image url
   };
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="img-square-wrapper p-2">
       
         <DataImage imageData={this.state.cardDataImage} />;
        
     </div>
  );
 }
}
```

**DataImage**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class DataImage extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

    this.state = {
     imageData: this.props.imageData,
   };
 }
  render() {
   return <img className="profile-img" src= 
    {this.state.imageData} alt="" />;
  }
 }
```

You can also look into the official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more information on **template literals**.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'allData')

This is the error I'm getting now after implementing it

Comment: What are you getting when you console log this statement `console.log("constructor dataitem ", this.state.allData);` ?